# Trying to find how a BigQuery table was deleted by searching the audit log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

A big query table was accidentally deleted. Fortunately we sink all our BQ audit logs into a dataset.

But I'm seeing some unexpected results. I was not seeing any delete operations for the table, then I broadened the scope of the query and found I could not see *any* ops for the table in the last 90 days.

I want to confirm my query is doing what I think it does. If this returns nothing does it really mean this table has not been touched in the last 90 days?

```
WHERE DATE(timestamp)  > timestamp_add(current_datetime, interval -90 day) AND
resource.labels.project_id = "myproject" AND
resource.type='bigquery_resource' AND
protopayload_auditlog.resourceName LIKE '%MyTable%'
LIMIT 10
```

I should add if I swap out `MyTable` with another table in the above query I can get results so I don't think it's a syntax issue.

Thinking about this more: could it be that the table was truncated in a way that was not considered an "admin" operation?

We sink the following logs into the dataset I'm searching:

```
cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity
cloudaudit_googleapis_data_access
cloudaudit_googleapis_system_event
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, it was a different operation that removed the table. I found it in the system log. It was removed due to a `InternalTableExpired` event.

```
SELECT 
resource.labels.project_id,
protopayload_auditlog.resourceName,
protopayload_auditlog.methodName,
protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail,
protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp 

FROM
`bombora-bi-prod.BomboraAuditLogs.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_system_event` 

WHERE
protopayload_auditlog.resourceName LIKE '%datasets/MyDataset/tables/MyTable%'

LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax looks ok. I recommend you to try larger intervals to confirm the query behaves as expected. Assuming the table is not empty, by increasing the days you must see something eventually.